# Wix .NET 4.0.3 for Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, wix, portable-class-library

I've got a project that contains a .NET Portable Class Library that targets .NET 4.0.

My understanding is that this means the client needs to have .NET 4.0.3 installed (KB2468871). How do I detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very close - you only had to google the update ID. So, the [original article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) contains the section called `Update detection information`. It lists the registry keys you should check the existence of to know whether the update is there or not.

**NOTE**: It lists two different keys (for Full and Client Profile versions respectively) in two groups (x86 and x64 respectively). You should choose the one which corresponds to your case.

And the rest is a technical details:

- author `<RegistrySearch>` element and wrap it into the property
- use the property in the launch conditions of your package

P.S. I understand it's late answer, but hopefully others can benefit.